# Atom ternjs and autocomplete working only for currently opened files

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, atom-editor

Is it possible to make Atom's autocomplite with the help of ternjs work without opening files? So I have this project structure.

[image: project structure]

Autocomplete suggestions appears only if d3.js or d3.min.js opened in another tab. And even if I keep them opened, when I try to call some method, for example, extent method, suggestion will not show any information about function's parameters.

.tern-project content

```
{
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "libs": [
    "browser",
    "jquery"
  ],
  "loadEagerly": [
    "/bower-components/d3/d3.js"
  ]
}
```

.gitignore

```
/bower_components
.tern-project
```

It is looks very strange, that I have to keep project files opened to make autocomplete work.